# 12.04 desktop is frozen. How to unfreeze the desktop?

Tags: 12.04

I have 12.04 on a duel boot partition with Windows 7, my desktop on 12.04 is frozen, I would like to upgrade but all I have access to is the command line. How do I fix or unfreeze the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

to update : `sudo apt-get update`

to upgrade : `sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo reboot`

after if the problem is still there ,if u use Nvidia drivers try to use the following commands(in order without restart) :

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

sudo nvidia-xconfig

sudo reboot
```

hopefully will work

Comment: @Fisher I tried your suggestion and it is still frozen. The video driver is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250.

Comment: Well,if u have AMD graphics,then check the infos from the next link: `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD`